# Moment js isAfter is always returning false

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
const endTime = moment.utc(end, 'HH:mm:ss').local().format('HH:mm:ss');
const startTime = moment.utc(start, 'HH:mm:ss').local().format('HH:mm:ss');
valid = moment(endTime).isAfter(startTime, 'hour');
```

So even if the end time is 7am and the start time is 6am  it still returns false

Comment: `moment(endTime).toString()` prints `invalid date`, because `endTime` is the string `17:00:00` and that's not a valid datetime from moment's perspective

Comment: You've marked an answer as correct but it doesn't deal with minutes and seconds like you seem to want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to compare the hour, just extract the hour of the start time and check if it's `<` the hour of the end time:

```js
const start = moment(new Date('2020-08-04T08:59:59.293Z'));
const end = moment(new Date('2020-08-04T10:59:59.293Z'));
 
const endTime = parseInt(moment.utc(end, 'HH:mm:ss').local().format('HH'));
const startTime = parseInt(moment.utc(start, 'HH:mm:ss').local().format('HH'));
const valid = startTime < endTime;

console.log(valid);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, don't mess with the formatting, you already have a start and end date:

```js
const start = moment(new Date('2020-08-04T08:59:59.293Z'));
const end = moment(new Date('2020-08-04T10:59:59.293Z'));
 
const valid = start.add(1, 'hour').isBefore(end);

console.log(valid);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have these strings:

```
const endTime = moment.utc(end, 'HH:mm:ss').local().format('HH:mm:ss'); // 17:00:00
const startTime = moment.utc(start, 'HH:mm:ss').local().format('HH:mm:ss'); // 16:00:00
```

You can just compare them without using moment. A string comparison should be just fine;

```
return endTime > startTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use moment at all ?

```js
const start = new Date();
const end = new Date();
end.setHours(end.getHours() + 1);
const startTime = start.getHours();
const endTime = end.getHours();
console.log(startTime, endTime, endTime < startTime )
```

Or if you don't want to check only for hours use
`end.getTime() < start.getTime()`

Comment: Everyone keeps ignoring minutes and seconds in these conversations. I think 17:04 should come out as later than 17:03, given the code he posted